# My iOS syncing headaches is a “White Elephant.” Can anything be done to reframe the question?

Tags: discussion, support

So, I’m an active member on a few of the Stack Exchange sites. No so much here, but I did as one question here that has received 10,000+ views but I consider a “White Elephant” due to many factors:

- [iOS 7 Syncing Headaches (iTunes 11)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107051/ios-7-syncing-headaches-itunes-11)

I initially posted this in frustration and hope that somehow there was a clear and sane way of dealing with—what I consider—Apple’s sloppy implementation of iOS/iTunes syncing since iOS7 hit and the iCloud became the new “sync service.”

Now if you read the post, please realize how I feel about it—and the related question—right now: I believe the question is utterly useless since 1+ year later the problem still exists, cannot be easily replicated, cannot be easily solved and is frustrating Apple iOS users all over.

I did stumble across a recent discovery [related to Wi-Fi sync failing on this site](http://www.mcelhearn.com/one-possible-explanation-for-some-itunes-sync-problems/):

> One issue that has been discussed on Apple’s support forums seems to
>   be caused by some incorrect handling of network activity by OS X. It
>   seems that iTunes – or, more correctly, the usbmuxd process that
>   handles connections between a Mac and and iOS device – has some
>   problems. This process opens network connections to the iOS device in
>   order to communicate with it. It opens two connections, one using IPv4
>   and another with IPv6, over TCP, to port 62078. If you run a command
>   in Terminal, you can see how many connections are open.

Wonderful! Someone made some progress! But still, it’s only really of concern for those who use Wi-Fi sync and not “tethered” sync. And the problem is not solved.

So personally, I believe my original question and answer thread—which barely exists—should be deleted. But how should a new question be written/framed? Should it simply be: *iOS and iTunes Syncing Issues Since iOS7 and OS X Sync Services Removed* or something else?

This is massively frustrating to me since I cannot help but feel that with 10,000+ views there are others struggling with this issue. But with no clear hope in site—and nobody else really chiming in on the thread—what can be done?

The question feels like a freak show. A “White Elephant” that’s interesting to look at but nobody knows what to do with it. And no real clues seem to be on the horizon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions shouldn't be deleted just because they haven't received an answer. Despite everything, an answer may still be found in the future and deleting the question doesn't help anyone as the original research is lost. Moving the research to a new question defeats the purpose and the original question may as well remain if this occurs.

Bounties are the main way attention is drawn to a question. Ask Different has very few active bounties running at any one time which means that bounties can be quite effective at attracting attention.

There's a silver [image] [Necromancer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) badge to be had for users who answer questions like this, so there's still a incentive to research and answer such questions.

I don't think the question needs to be *reframed* as such, but providing an update with the latest information might be beneficial. Furthermore, a bounty will attract attention and may get the question seen by someone who has some crucial information in resolving the problem.